# How can I get the OOB samples used for each tree in random forest model R?

Tags: r, random-forest

Is it possible to get the OOB samples used by random forest algorithm for each tree ?
I'm using R language.
I know that RandomForest algorithm uses almost 66% of the data (selected randomly) to grow up each tree, and 34 % of the data as OOB samples to measure the OOB error, but I don't know how to get those OOB samples for each tree ?

Any idea ?

Comment: could you read my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67817875/err-rate-in-randomforest-package-how-can-i-retrieve-it Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `randomForest` package, you just need to set the `keep.inbag` argument to `TRUE`.

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(1)
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, keep.inbag = TRUE)
```

The output list will contain an n by ntree matrix that can be accessed by the name `inbag`.

```
dim(rf$inbag)
# [1] 150 500

rf$inbag[1:5, 1:3]
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# 1    0    1    0
# 2    1    1    0
# 3    1    0    1
# 4    1    0    1
# 5    0    0    2
```

The values in the matrix tell you how many times a sample was in-bag.  For example, the value of 2 in row 5 column 3 above says that the 5th observation was included in-bag twice for the 3rd tree.

As a bit of background here, a sample can show up in-bag more than once (hence the 2) because by default the sampling is done with replacement.

You can also sample without replacement via the `replace` parameter.

```
set.seed(1)
rf2 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, keep.inbag = TRUE, replace = FALSE)
```

And now we can verify that without replacement, the maximum number of times any sample is included is once.

```
# with replacement, the maximum number of times a sample is included in a tree is 7
max(rf$inbag)
# [1] 7

# without replacemnet, the maximum number of times a sample is included in a tree is 1
max(rf2$inbag)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: just to confirm, the documentation provided by `?randomForest` (attributed to argument `keep.inbag` states that the matrix provides "which samples are “in-bag” in which trees (but not how many times, if sampling with replacement)". Do you think the documentation is just out of date?