# Is there a way to get the training scoring history based on in-bag samples (instead of out-of-bag samples) in h2o.randomForest()?

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I would like to know the in-bag training metrics of my random forest fit in h2o R version:

```
rf_cv = h2o.randomForest(x = x, y = y,
                         training_frame = cali,
                         ntrees = 800,
                         nfolds = 5,
                         mtries = 3,
                         seed = 98)
```

When I print the scoring history I get the following training metrics:

```
> rf_cv@model$scoring_history
number_of_trees training_rmse training_mae training_deviance
1               0.70767       0.45476      0.50080
...
800             0.47283       0.30862      0.22357
```

But those metrics are from the out-of bag samples, as shown in the performance summary:

```
> h2o.performance(rf_cv)
H2ORegressionMetrics: drf
** Reported on training data. **
** Metrics reported on Out-Of-Bag training samples **

MSE:  0.2235729
RMSE:  0.4728349
MAE:  0.3086151
RMSLE:  0.1403068
Mean Residual Deviance :  0.2235729
```

I know I could just get the overall in-bag training performance with `h2o.performance(rf_cv, data = train)` but I need the scoring history. I've gone through the documentation and looked for similar questions but I've found nothing so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but I took some time and also looked a bit into it and as far as I can tell, there is no way to retrieve an in-bag score. It wouldn't really make sense to calculate it for a random forest. I also didn't find anything related to the out-of-bag or in-bag  samples, so I would assume they also don't get stored. However, if you'd manage to find them somewhere you could probably use `h2o.getModelTree()` to produce some kind of score.

You could also go and look into the [source code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/43f8ab952a69a8bc9484bd0ffac909b6e3e820ca) and see if you get any deeper insights.

I also found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728851/how-can-i-get-the-oob-samples-used-for-each-tree-in-random-forest-model-r) which might help you. However, it does not use `h2o` but the `randomForest` R library, if that is an option for you. There you can retrieve the OOB samples, thus you know what the in-bag samples are and you can then score them yourself, but I have not done this myself.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I'll look into the options that you provided. Upvoted but it's not displayed since I'm new to stack :(